# How to use ES2015 Template strings in an Ember helper

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

Ember > 2.0 + [Ember suave](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-suave) are telling me:

> "requireTemplateStringsForConcatenation: Using manual concatenation
>   with strings is not allowed at helpers/svg-icon.js"

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function svgIcon(iconName) {
  return Ember.String.htmlSafe("<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href='#icon-" +  iconName + "'></use></svg>");
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(svgIcon);
```

I've just come from a meetup where Ember.string.fmt was discussed and sounded promising ~ but that has been deprecated and suggests you use ES2015 Template Strings.

Reading about those here: http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/

I am unclear about how 'manual' concatenation works - what the problem would be - and well, the whole thing.

`return Ember.String.htmlSafe("<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href='#icon-${iconName}'></use></svg>");` ?

Implementation and reasoning happily accepted.

Comment: you ll want to replace your `"` with ` (backtick)

Comment: AH - they were so small - I didn't notice them in the docs. You should add your comment as an answer! Thanks.

Comment: Close voting as typo is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: I don't see typo as an option in the vote to close. I also think that other people might also misread the docs. If someone throws Ember suave on a large projects - there will be many searches before they clear up all the warnings.

Comment: The cv reason is under off topic > simple typographic error.